# The names of sheets are changed when users use different languages

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use the formula `{'Form Responses 1'! A1: G; 'Form Responses 2'! A2: G; ...}` to get data from all sheets into one sheet. However, when the user uses a language other than English, the sheets' names are changed, and the related formulas are corrupted.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem, thank you in advance.

The code:

```
 function copy() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var SpssId = ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('AH6').getValue();
    var destinationSpss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpssId);
    for (var i = 1; i < destinationSpss.getNumSheets(); i++) {
    var index = destinationSpss.getSheetByName('index');
    index.getRange(i+1,2,1,4)
    .setFormulas([["='Form Responses "+i+"'!B2","='Form Responses "+i+"'!D2","='Form Responses "+i+"'!C2","='Form Responses "+i+"'!E2"]]);
    }}
```

Comment: Since sheet names are editable anyway, this method of relying on sheet names is going to be brittle, even without the language problem. Can you give some more details about this project? How much control do you have over these other sheets? Who creates these other sheets? Can you ask users to give them custom names?

Comment: Hi Adam Stevenson, my Project is a add-on, giving each student a quiz. Because the tests are different, I have to create a separate form for each student, and so their responses are sent to different sheets. I have to get data from those sheets into a sheet to aggregate scores. If I used a loop, I could use sheet [0], sheet [1], sheet [2], .... However, doing so takes a long time. So I use arrays to write formulas that link sheets as shown in the question. I tried {'Sheets (0)'! A1: G; 'Sheets (1)'! A2: G ...} but it doesn't work. Do you have a way to fix this, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I wasn't sure if you were using Apps Script or not. It sounds like you are if you're building an add-on. It would be helpful to see some of the Apps Script code you've already written. You say, "If I used a loop, I could use sheet [0], sheet [1], sheet [2], .... However, doing so takes a long time." Can you clarify this statement? I actually think a loop might work better here than an array formula, but I would need to see your code to see how we can optimize.

Comment: Actually I used a loop, my code looks like this:

Comment: Can you please clarify what the issue is here and what is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to get the values from sheets named Form Responses 1, Form Responses 2, ... into the sheet named index, with array formula. But when my users use different languages on their spreadsheets the names of the sheets change and my formula crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the code. It was very helpful to see what you had so far.

Can we assume that `index` is the only sheet in the destination spreadsheet that is not one of the form response sheets? Judging from your code, it seems like we can assume this.

So then we can just use [`Spreadsheet.getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) to get an array of all the sheets and [`Sheet.getName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getname) to get their names, regardless of language:

```js
function copy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SpssId = ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('AH6').getValue();
  var destinationSpss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpssId);

  var sheets = destinationSpss.getSheets()  // Get an array of the sheets
  var index = destinationSpss.getSheetByName('index');
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheetName = sheets[i].getName();
    if (sheetName === 'index') break;
    index.getRange(i + 1, 2, 1, 4)
      .setFormulas([[`="${sheetName}"!B2`,`="${sheetName}"!D2`,`="${sheetName}"!C2`,`="${sheetName}"!E2`]])
  }
}
```

(I'm using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#template_literals) to format the formula strings, which just makes the code a little cleaner, but this is not necessary of course.)

Can you always assume that the `index` sheet is at index 0? I'm not sure if you can, so I would expand your for-loop to include `i = 0` and add the check `if (sheetName === 'index') break;` to break if you're on the `index` sheet.

As an aside, you'll see I also moved `var index = destinationSpss.getSheetByName('index');` outside of the for-loop. The App Scripts API can be slow for certain operations, and since you're referencing the same `index` sheet for every iteration, your code will be faster if you call for this `index` sheet just once.

Comment: Thank you so much, for helping me get the names of the sheets without using the names directly, and I also know how to get an element out of the loop if it's not necessarily in the loop.